# Cookie always null?

Tags: javascript, caching

I want to check if the cookie is existing or not

The problem is it is always returning to null if i check it

```
if ($.cookie('cookieCreditDash') == null) {

   //CODE ALWAYS ENTER HERE... :(
            alert("no cookie");    
            $.getJSON(url, function(data) {
                saveCreditCookie(data);
            });
} else{
            alert("with cookie");
            var data =  JSON.parse($.cookie("cookieCreditDash"));
}

function saveCreditCookie(jsonData){
    var date = new Date();
    date.setTime(date.getTime() + (30 * 60 * 1000));
    $.cookie("cookieCreditDash", JSON.stringify(jsonData), {expires: date});
 }
```

WHYYY>??

BTW, I used the following plugin:

```
(function ($, document, undefined) {
        var pluses = /\+/g;
        function raw(s) {
            return s;
        }
        function decoded(s) {
            return decodeURIComponent(s.replace(pluses, ' '));
        }
        var config = $.cookie = function (key, value, options) {
            // write
            if (value !== undefined) {
                options = $.extend({}, config.defaults, options);
                if (value === null) {
                    options.expires = -1;
                }
                if (typeof options.expires === 'number') {
                    var days = options.expires, t = options.expires = new Date();
                    t.setDate(t.getDate() + days);
                }
                value = config.json ? JSON.stringify(value) : String(value);
                return (document.cookie = [
                    encodeURIComponent(key), '=', config.raw ? value : encodeURIComponent(value),
                    options.expires ? '; expires=' + options.expires.toUTCString() : '', // use expires attribute, max-age is not supported by IE
                    options.path    ? '; path=' + options.path : '',
                    options.domain  ? '; domain=' + options.domain : '',
                    options.secure  ? '; secure' : ''
                ].join(''));
            }

            // read
            var decode = config.raw ? raw : decoded;
            var cookies = document.cookie.split('; ');
            for (var i = 0, parts; (parts = cookies[i] && cookies[i].split('=')); i++) {
                if (decode(parts.shift()) === key) {
                    var cookie = decode(parts.join('='));
                    return config.json ? JSON.parse(cookie) : cookie;
                }
            }
            return null;
        };
        config.defaults = {};
        $.removeCookie = function (key, options) {
            if ($.cookie(key) !== null) {
                $.cookie(key, null, options);
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        };
    })(jQuery, document);
```

Comment: It would be interesting to see what `alert(JSON.stringify(jsonData))`  in `saveCreditCookie` produces. If, for some reason, it turns out to be `null` then that may explain it.

Comment: you're right.. the jsonData is null that's why the cookie is null. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

What is `$.cookie`? a jquery plugin?

Did you try using `document.cookie` for setting cookie instead of `$.cookie`.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/document.cookie

Answer (score 1):

As I can see from documentation [jquery.cookie.js](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie): `expires` is number of days

```
if ($.cookie('cookieCreditDash') == null)
{
     $('div').text("no cookie");
     $.cookie("cookieCreditDash", 'test', {expires: 1});
} else{
     var data =  $.cookie("cookieCreditDash");
     $('div').text("with cookie: " + data);        
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/HeGhf/

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are using [jQuery cookie plugin](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie).

Besides cookie expiry issues, you might also want to check your cookie path, making it available to all paths on your domain. You can do so by writing following code,

```
$.cookie("cookieCreditDash", "Value", { path: '/' });
```

Without `{path: '/'}`, cookie path will be limited to current path level only.