# Cookie JSON for particular user

Tags: jquery, cookies

I have a problem with the cookie I've created.

Related to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12757271/cookie-always-null), my cookie is now working. The problem is if I changed the user, the same cookie is still being shown. Are there ways to ensure that the particular cookie is for that particular user? Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that your previous code only triggers cookie creation when it's null

```
if ($.cookie('cookieCreditDash') == null) {
  ...
}
```

So I suggest you just clear the cookie everytime a user-logout event is triggered.

```
$.removeCookie('cookieCreditDash');
```

Or, if you can change users without any user logging out, then trigger `saveCreditCookie` function everytime you change users. Not sure though how that's detected in your application.

```
$.getJSON(url, function(data) {
  saveCreditCookie(data);
});
```